# Prove that the centralizer $C_{D_8}(A)=A$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, dihedral-groups

> Let $D_8$ be the dihedral group of order $8$. Using the generators and relations, we have
> $D_8=⟨r,s∣r^4=s^2=1,sr=r^{−1}s⟩$.
>
> (a) Let $A$ be the subgroup of $D_8$ generated by $r$, that is, $A=\{ 1,r,r^2,r^3\}$.
> Prove that the centralizer $C_{D_8}(A)=A$.

Proof,

- Since $C_{D_8}(A) \leq D_8$ , By lagrange's theorem order of $C_{D_8}(A)$ might be $1,2,4$ or $8$
- Since $A$ is abelian group, It is clear that for any $g \in A$, $gag^{-1}=a \space \forall a \in {A}$.

  That is $A \subseteq C_{D_8}(A) $ this follows $|C_{D_8}(A)| \geq 4$
- Note that $srs^{-1}=r^3 \not= r$. Therefore $s \not \in C_{D_8}(A)$. This follows $|C_{D_8}(A)| \not= 8$.
- Hence $|C_{D_8}(A)|=4$ and $C_{D_8}(A)$ must be $A$

Can anyone verify my answer?

Comment: You could explain how your third point implies that $rs,r^2s,r^3s$ cannot be in the centralizer as well. Anyway, that is easy to see and the proof is good.

Comment: @AHappyMathematician thank you